# Python Selenium Cookies

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookie

Пытался сам написать, искал много в инете, как загрузить данные куки для определённого сайта из переменных в Селениум (Не сохранять и загружать файлы куки а именно из переменных взять)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Помогите написать код который будет авторизироваться на сайте через куки которые будут указаны в скрипте в переменных. Эти переменные с куками нужно как то засунуть в селениум, сколько не пытаюсь вообще идей нет как это сделать.